# Changing all post images URL to a new URL from the post excerpt field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

It's my first time posting here.

I have a fairly simple script that I'm trying to get working on my word press website. I'm essentially trying to make a loop that goes through all the posts on a page and changes that URL to another URL

I am going to be pasting the new URL in the post excerpt field. What I want to happen is that once a user clicks on the image of a post on the homepage, they are taken to the URL that I specified on the post excerpt field of that respective post.

here is the code I came up with.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {   
        $('ul.g1-collection-items li.g1-collection-item').each(function(){
            var that = $(this);
            var excerpt_link = $(<?php echo get_the_excerpt ?>);
            that.find('.entry-featured-media a').attr('href', excerpt_link);
        });
    });
</script>
```

But as expected, this doesn't work. Also, using this code seems to only work on the URL slug, not the entire URL

Any thoughts? Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The code dosen't work because you're mixing jQuery foreach loop without a Wordpress foreach loop. I get what you're trying to do, but you're doing it wrong.

In the part where you have the loop for posts just add the

```
<?php echo get_the_excerpt();?>
```

And put it on the anchor tag of the image, and you're done, no need for jQuery.

P.S. you also wrote the get_the_excerpt wrong, it wouldn't work. It's a function so it needs a ()

Comment: Also worth noting that `get_the_excerpt` and `get_the_content` are two different fields. Sometimes `get_the_excerpt` might not be enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response! I tried doing that but the theme I am using is very complicated and I can not locate where they placed the file for this, this is why I am trying to find a way to do it without editing the theme itself.

Comment: You need to show us the structure of the HTML you're trying to get, and also If is your excerpt showing with that link? Even thought I highly doubt that since what you wrote.

You need to modify the theme in order to get this working.